# Seasonal Arima not being able to model seasonal components efficiently

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

The following is a (not perfectly)seasonal time series sequence that I am trying to fit an ARIMA model to:

[data plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPBdL.png)

I made it stationary(confirmed by adf test) using first order regular diff and first order seasonal diff, after which it looked like this:

[acf and pacf of the stationary data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyMUr.png)

The seasonal components are at 12 and 24, both significant in the acf plot, while in the pacf plot, only the 12th one is significant.

I tried a lot of combinations for p,d,a,P,D,Q but no matter what the combination, the residuals always seem to have the first seasonal lag as significant in both the acf and pacf plots.

I decided to go with ARIMA(4,1,4)(1,1,1)[96] (even though 12 is the frequency of data(monthly), it happens to show seasonality at roughly 96 intervals, i.e. in 8 years) because it was giving the best log-likelihood score, but still it doesn't fits the seasonal components.

[residual acf and pacf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNjsz.png)

Can anyone please suggest me what should be improved/tried in order for the model to fit all the lags?

Sharing the r file and dataset here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1okMUkBj2W2nF9NkoX4igq2-7QP-cgnSO?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried the automated ARIMA https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html ? It's better if you can share your data and code so it's possible to reproduce what your seeing.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for your reply, I did try auto.arima, the results were pretty much the same, the residuals were not white noise. I have shared the code and data as asked.

Comment: Oh, okay I saw the link that you shared now, yes that's what I tried to find the combinations of p,q,d,P,Q,D..